# Flutter ListView.builder - how to achieve a complex layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I got stuck while trying to find a way to display a more complex layout using a ListView.builder in flutter.

1. I get a list of items via http.
2. I use ListView.builder to display them with optimal performance because the number of items i get varies.
3. Here is the problem: I need to display the items in the following way:
   First item should always be Full width, 1 card, then items 2 & 3 should come bellow the first item but in a column one next to another .. and this layout should continue to repeat until end of items.length

Here is an example;

---

[image]

---

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your _httpCall future function return an array and here is your code;

```
FutureBuilder<List>(
  future: _httpCall(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData)
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: (snapshot.data.length * (2 / 3)).floor(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index % 3 == 0)
            return Container(
              // Your full-width item
              width: double.maxFinite,
              child: Text("${snapshot.data[index]}"),
            );
          else
            return Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text("${snapshot.data[index]}"),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text("${snapshot.data[index + 1]}"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
        },
      );
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
)
```